# Parsing JSON in Controller w/ HTTParty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook-graph-api, httparty

In my controller I have the following code...

```
response = HTTParty.get('https://graph.facebook.com/zuck')
logger.debug(response.body.id)
```

I am getting a NoMethodError / undefined method `id'

If I do...

```
logger.debug(response.body)
```

It outputs as it should...

```
{"id":"4","name":"Mark Zuckerberg","first_name":"Mark","last_name":"Zuckerberg","link":"http:\/\/www.facebook.com\/zuck","username":"zuck","gender":"male","locale":"en_US"}
```

One would think it's **response.body.id**, but obviously that's not working. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Try this:

```
body = JSON.parse(response.body)
id = body["id"]
```

For this kind of thing, I'd recommend either a) using [Koala](https://github.com/arsduo/koala) or b) create a class using httparty. You can then set `format: json` to auto parse the returned json. See [here](http://httparty.rubyforge.org/rdoc/) and [here](http://www.railstips.org/blog/archives/2008/07/29/it-s-an-httparty-and-everyone-is-invited/)

Comment: To elaborate a bit on this answer: you cannot simply treat the response of your `HTTParty.get` like it would be an ActiveRecord model. Unfortunately you will only get a hash back and not a model.

Comment: It looks like the current version of HTTParty interprets the response from Facebook as JSON without having to do any extra coercion.

Answer (score 14):

You can force the response to be treated as JSON using `HTTParty.get` like so:

```
response = HTTParty.get("http://itunes.apple.com/search",
    {query: {term: 'tame impala'}, format: :json})

response['results'][0]['trackName']

=> "Let It Happen"
```

Comment: Thanks noticing `format`, from the code I thought it's `parser`.

Answer (score 10):

You can use `response['id']` in case that the response `Content-Type` is `application/json` or also `response.parse_response` to get a Hash generated from the JSON payload.

```
response = HTTParty.get('https://graph.facebook.com/zuck')

payload = response.parsed_response

logger.debug(payload['id'])
```

Note: `parsed_response` is a Hash, only if the response `Content-Type` is `application/json`, otherwise `HTTParty` will return it as a string. For enforcing a Hash, in case the response does not return `application/json`, you can pass the `format` as a parameter `HTTParty.get(url, format: :json)`.

Comment: Note that you may need to do `HTTParty.get('https://graph.facebook.com/zuck', format: :json)` - otherwise the `parsed_response` could be the raw JSON string instead of a Ruby hash.

Comment: @HenrikN If the response content-type is `application/json`, I don't need `format: :json`.

Comment: @HenrikN I added a note to clarify it :)

Answer (score 0):

HTTParty should automatically parse the content based on the content type returned. Something fishy seems to be going on with zuck's json.

```
pry(main)> HTTParty.get('https://graph.facebook.com/zuck')
=> "{\"id\":\"4\",\"first_name\":\"Mark\",\"gender\":\"male\",\"last_name\":\"Zuckerberg\",\"link\":\"https:\\/\\/www.facebook.com\\/zuck\",\"locale\":\"en_US\",\"name\":\"Mark Zuckerberg\",\"username\":\"zuck\"}"
```

But this works OK:

```
pry(main)> HTTParty.get('http://echo.jsontest.com/foo/bar/baz/foo')
=> {"baz"=>"foo", "foo"=>"bar"}
```

Don't forget to `require 'httparty'` if you're trying that in the console yourself.